# image should remain the same after updation of record in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am uploading some data to the db that contain title, news date and image, but when i want to update it i am facing problems.what i want to do basically if i update all the row except image then updation do not take place. what i want basically when i have to update lets suppose title only then it should update it but all other data should remain same but problem is that i have to select image again from my pc in updation. my scenario is that i just save the name in db not the whole path and hard code the path where ever i need to display the image

here is html

```
 <div class="row">
                            <label>Image upload</label>
                            <div class="right"><input type="file" name="file" value="<?php echo $row['images'];?>" /></div>
                        </div>
```

here is php

```
   if(($_GET['mod']=='edit') && (isset($_POST['hidden'])))
{




    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $images));
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/pjpeg"))

        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
           if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {

            echo $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload-images/" . $images);
            $update="UPDATE headline SET 
                                                headline_title  = '$title',   
                                                headline_des    = '$description',   
                                                month           = '$month_name', 
                                                day             = '$day_name', 
                                                year            = '$year_name', 
                                                featured        = '$featured',
                                                headline        = '$headline',
                                                images          = '$images' 
                                                where id        = ".$_GET['id']."";
             $result = mysql_query($update);    

              }
            }
```

Comment: mind sharing some snippets explaining what and how you are doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting the form again will cause the new value of the file input which will be **empty** 
so you have to check if it's empty or not and act according to the status

For example

```
if($_FILES['file']['name'] != "")
{
      //upload the image with what ever you want 
      //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target.$image );
      //the SQL query should contain the updating the image column 
         if(($_GET['mod']=='edit') && (isset($_POST['hidden'])))
         {




echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $images));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]   == "image/pjpeg"))

    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
       if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {

        echo $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload-images/" . $images);
        $update="UPDATE headline SET 
                                            headline_title  = '$title',   
                                            headline_des    = '$description',   
                                            month           = '$month_name', 
                                            day             = '$day_name', 
                                            year            = '$year_name', 
                                            featured        = '$featured',
                                            headline        = '$headline',
                                            images          = '$images' 
                                            where id        = ".$_GET['id']."";
         $result = mysql_query($update);    

          }
        }
}
else
{
      //SQL update without image 
        $update="UPDATE headline SET 
                                            headline_title  = '$title',   
                                            headline_des    = '$description',   
                                            month           = '$month_name', 
                                            day             = '$day_name', 
                                            year            = '$year_name', 
                                            featured        = '$featured',
                                            headline        = '$headline'
                                            WHERE id        = ".$_GET['id']."";
         $result = mysql_query($update);    

}
```

if you don't want the image to be edited simply you can remove it from the update and the form used for that or but it's path in hidden input

Hope this will help

According to your comment the query should look something like this

```
        $update="UPDATE headline SET 
                                            headline_title  = '$title',   
                                            headline_des    = '$description',   
                                            month           = '$month_name', 
                                            day             = '$day_name', 
                                            year            = '$year_name', 
                                            featured        = '$featured',
                                            headline        = '$headline'
                                            WHERE id        = ".$_GET['id']."";
         $result = mysql_query($update);
```

**I think you need to use good intending to make your code more readable and maintainable in the future :)**

Comment: yes in updation imge filed gives me empty value but i want it to get that image from db which i insert during insertion because this time i dont want to change the image but only title or content

Comment: if you don't want to change the image , remove the image field from the query

Comment: check it now .. is this what you want ?

Comment: no infact i want to change the imgae as well but the problem is that for example i insert data in db every thing correctly but suddenly i saw i have enterd the wrong title and i want to update it the why should i upload the image again this time i will just correct my title and click update button, but this not happens it force me to upload image as well. when i selct the specific news for udation all the data fetxhed from db and displayed correctly in their respective field but it cant get the image name from db, once it will get it it will solve all my problm ik now

Comment: with refrence of ur edited code above what will i do if i have to update image as well

Comment: thanx alot SEDZ it helped i m so duffer very easy solution it had but i was thinking very complex

Answer (score 0):

Solution

1. check the file is not empty: `if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']))`
2. Take update query with mentioning image column in your table  in IF statement,
   **if images not uploaded, then it will upload**.
3. Take update query without mentioning image column in your table  in ELSE statement,if file is empty, it will upload

***CONCLUSION***

Next time when you update any other field the image won't get disappeared, meaning file path wont be empty in your database, and if already present it won't change unless you manually change it..